# AMP HTML Conversion tracking

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

We are trialling some AMP landing pages and have added the analytics code to our landing pages. These landing pages pass users on to a standard form page.

Our main analytics is showing large volumes of traffic to these AMP landing pages with an acceptable bounce rate, but zero conversions - even though the campaigns are showing the ad group that uses the AMP pages as landing pages have conversions.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How this is implemented, is an Adwords conversion code or they are being imported from Google Analytics? Why I asked this, because the Client id in AMP and in the regular domain is different, Also the AMP is a CND content. So if you user lands into AMP page and them goes to your regular domain. For Google Analytics you have 2 differents users with 2 different source medium (the regular is your-domain.cdn.google.com).  Provide the code/configuration of this and we can provide a possible solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://amphtml.wordpress.com/2016/08/11/fast-ad-landing-pages-with-amp/), when you input a canonical destination URL for a creative, the ad server can switch it to the AMP version of the URL (with trafficker consent) using the [AMP URL API](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/acceleratedmobilepageurl/rest/). The ad server can also embed code required by the creative to pre-fetch and pre-connect to the landing page. Ad servers like DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) are integrating such features over the next couple of quarters to make trafficking of AMP landing pages easy.

Also, from this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/ads/amp-analytics):

> Type attribute value: `googleadwords`
>
> Adds support for Google AdWords conversion tracking and remarketing. See more details in the AdWords help center for [conversion tracking](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en) and [remarketing](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453998?hl=en). Both tags can be used independent of each other.